# Multiple channel entry fields per row on publish/edit page

Tags: channel-entries, channel

Kind of noob question for EE but is it possible to have multiple channel entry fields per row on a channel (publish/edit) back end? I'm at the point of adding channel fields where are numbers only and came kind of "messy" on publish/edit page.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use the [Publish Layouts](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/content/publish_page_layouts.html) feature. You can drag and drop fields into place and adjust their widths as you please.

Comment: Funny - I have never checked what is for that toolbar